# Cocos2D, CCMenuAdvanced Implementation Error: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CCMenuAdvanced" linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, clang, xcode4.5

Ok.  I'm starting a new Cocos2D template to try to figure out how CCMenuAdvanced works, exactly.  Started with a Cocos2D 2.1 b2 project with no physics, added the CCMenuAdvanced.h and CCMenuAdvanced.m files to my project, deleted the boilerplate code from the HelloWorldLayer.m init method and everything runs fine.  Black screen.  Looks to me like I imported all the libraries as I should, when I type in anything having to do with CCMenuAdvance, it autocompletes, so that appears to be working fine.  Here's all I put in the HelloWorldLayer init method:

```
CCMenuItemImage *scrollableSprite = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:@"640x2272ScrollableImage.png"
                                                    selectedImage:@"640x2272ScrollableImage.png"
                                                           target:self
                                                         selector:@selector(iDunnoYet)];
```

As expected, it compiles and runs with an unused variable 'sprite' warning, but it runs fine.  As soon as I add this line of code to the project, expecting to get another unused variable error (menu):

```
CCMenuAdvanced *menu = [CCMenuAdvanced menuWithItems:scrollableSprite, nil];
```

I get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CCMenuAdvanced", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in HelloWorldLayer.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've commented out that line and again, it builds and runs fine.  I've read two different things that might throw this error:  1) that I imported a file or library twice in my project, and 2) that I haven't properly included a necessary library in my build settings.  To the first, I've checked my headers and they look fine.  I only #imported the CCMenuAdvanced.h file in my HelloWorldLayer.h file.  To the second, it's a Cocos2D template which works fine without the above-mentioned line of code, so I think all the necessary libraries should already be included.

Anyway, if someone could possibly point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it.  Thanks in advance.  Of course, I can supply more code, if need be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that CCMenuAdvanced.m is added to your project's target. Select the file, open the Utilities view and review the target membership of the file. There should be a checkbox next to the file. Like this:

[image]

Comment: Ay... Steffen, you're the best.  If this app gets bought out by Zynga for millions of dollars, as I fully expect it to...you're getting a MAJOR donation.  :)  Thank you so much!

Comment: Even though I can't see the image you posted, regardless of which browser I try it in.  Hmm.  Thanks again.

Comment: But what if Zynga simply copies your game and goes on to make millions? :)

Comment: Hopefully, I will have made at least a few million by then.  :)  But, if not!  I'll buy you a nice gift basket or something.  Then sue Zynga in hopes of a multi-million dollar settlement.